# What is a correct way to update Emacs?

Tags: install

Given:

Linux Mint 20.1 (64 bit)

Emacs 27.1

I want to update Emacs.
What is the correct (best) way to do this?

Before I remove totally Emacs and install new version. But I thinks it's not a good way.

Comment: `sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade emacs` perhaps? Linux Mint is a Debian derivative. I think the invocation is correct, but I'm a Fedora user, so if it's wrong, I hope somebody corrects it.

Comment: You need `sudo` on both `apt-get` commands but other than that, it is correct.

Comment: Youve tagged this `init-file`?? I wonder if you are actually meaning to ask "How to clean up my init?"  Equivalent q from other side: Why do you want to "upgrade" your emacs?  What exactly is unsatisfactory with your 27.1?

Comment: @Rusi Emacs 28 was released. So I always download latest version.

Comment: Well [version 29](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/etc/NEWS) is also available -- Doesnt mean its a good idea to chase that rainbow!

Comment: @Rusi I use only Emacs from official site: http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/

Comment: @NickD Success did "sudo apt-get upgrade emacs". But after start Emacs again run version 27.2.

Comment: There may not be a newer version available yet.

Comment: How do I know how is my Emacs installed originally? When I do which -a emacs I get:              
/usr/local/bin/emacs
/opt/local/bin/emacs
/usr/local/bin/emacs

Answer (score 2):

*What is a correct way to update Emacs (or anything)?* It is **the way you installed it**.

Definitely do not run things, e. g., `sudo apt update && apt upgrade emacs`. This will only work if you installed Emacs with `sudo apt install emacs`. This could possibly throw you in a sticky loop. What if you installed Emacs as `emacs-snapshot` like this (from [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-elisp/+archive/ubuntu/ppa))

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-elisp/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install emacs-snapshot
```

Now if you did install `emacs-snapshot` and ended up running `sudo apt update && apt upgrade emacs`, it'll try to overwrite some packages that are already installed by the snapshot package and obviously fail and you'll end up with a strange broken pipe error. *Surely*, I have never done anything like this.

Also, I hear kids these days are installing [Emacs as a snap](https://snapcraft.io/emacs), in which case I am sure there is some snap update command you should run.

You could also have installed Emacs with whatever software store that comes with Mint--in that case just go back to that store and click some update button.

Finally, if you installed Emacs by compiling source, just do that again with updated source?

Answer (score 0):

Any way that you want to do it is correct.

I’ve never used Linux Mint myself, but presumably it has a Software Manager or Package Manager that you can use to install things. I am sure that it includes Emacs amongst the list of things that it can install, though sometimes these things take some time to get the latest version of things. You can probably install Emacs this way, and have it automatically updated just like any other application on the system. That might be the most convenient way to do it, but any other way of doing things will be just as good.